# How to interpret Scala's SIP notation

Tags: scala

I was reading a SIP (Scala Improvement Process) document and found this syntax:

> We introduce a new form of expression for processed strings: Syntax:
>
> ```
> SimpleExpr1  ::= … | processedStringLiteral
> processedStringLiteral
>              ::= alphaid`"' {printableChar \ (`"' | `$') | escape} `"' 
>               |  alphaid `"""' {[`"'] [`"'] char \ (`"' | `$') | escape} {`"'} `"""'
> escape       ::= `$$' 
>               |  `$' letter { letter | digit } 
>               |  `$'BlockExpr
> alphaid      ::=  upper idrest
>               |  varid
> ```

I would like to be able to understand this syntax but I don't even know:

- What it's called? (if it's called anything)
- If it is specific to SIP's

Everything that **I think I know** are assumptions from other programming languages or specifications, like:

- `|` denotes an alternative unless used at start of line, then it just says the line continues.
- `\` is an escape character
- This notation starts by defining a concept at the cost of other concepts, i.e. `processedStringLiteral` is defined at the cost of `alphaid`, `escape` and `printableChar` (even tho I have no idea where `printableChar` is).

The questions:

- Are my assumptions correct?
- What about the remaining notation like `::=`, `"'`.
- How would I read this as if I was reading english? I.e: "A processed string literal starts with a letter followed by a space... " (assuming I can even read it like this).

Comment: The notation is called EBNF, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form, but it's written in latex, so things between ` and ' are actually terminals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary:

- This notation is called Extended Backus-Naur Form.
- It is not specific to SIPs.
- Your assumptions are partially correct.
- I'll explain what those symbols mean in the longer version
- I'll give examples of English translations in the longer version
- Yes this is a fragment. Not all definitions are present.

Longer version:

What you are seeing is as, @pedrofurla points out, Extended Backus-Naur Form, which is unfortunately not well defined. [This link](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/ebnf.html) lists many different variants of it that you might find in the wild. Like pseudo-code you'll come to see a lot of conventions that appear over and over again and therefore in most practical cases it is unambiguous what the EBNF means. It is used to specify a certain grammar*, i.e. a "valid" subset for the task at hand of all strings (e.g. syntactically correct code in a given language). It is not specific to SIPs.

It is generally as (with an exception in this particular variant being used) an additive specification. Each line is a new rule that adds a new kind of valid string to the valid subset we are defining of all strings.

What I describe next will be the particular variant used here, but most other variants are similar with minor syntactic differences or renamings.

Every rule (often called a production rule) consists of two parts: a variable name (usually called a nonterminal symbol) on the left hand side followed by `::=` which you can read as "is defined as" and a series of characters that then define the variable.

In this particular case things quoted by `` ` `` and `'` are constants (usually called a terminal symbol), that is atomic strings that are always considered valid. All nonquoted names are variables (again nonterminal symbols) that refer to a string deemed valid by the rule that defined that variable.

`|` is indeed meant to be read as "or."

`\` is the exception to the additive nature of this notation. It is meant to be read as "except for." It is the same symbol that is used in mathematics to denote set difference (subtracting the elements of one set from another).

`{...}` is read as "0 or more of these."

`[...]` is read as "0 or 1 of these."

`(...)` is traditional grouping/association like you might find in any programming language.

Finally  (just a space) is used for concatenation.

Let's put it all together for some basic examples!

```
trivialidentifier ::= `this' | `that'
```

In English: "The set of strings I consider valid are all strings that are `trivialidentifiers`. `trivialidentifiers` are 'this' or 'that'." Hence the only strings considered valid here are "this" and "that".

Let's try something more:

```
name ::= `John' | `Mary' | `Jane'
verb ::= `runs' | `walks'
sentence ::= (name \ `Mary') ` ' verb
```

In English: "Here are the valid strings we care about: A `name` is 'John', 'Mary', or 'Jane'. A `verb` is 'runs' or 'walks'. A `sentence` is any `name` except for 'Mary' followed by a space and any `verb`." So for example "John runs" is a valid `sentence` but "Mary runs" is not.

And now for something recursive:

```
thing ::= `a' | { thing }
```

In English: "Here are our valid strings we care about. A `thing` is either 'a' or zero or more repetitions of `thing`." In other words any repetition of "a", such as "", "a", "aa", "aaa", etc.

Note that the above is equivalent to

```
thing ::= ` ' | `a' | `a' [ ( thing \ ` ' ) ]
```

Now let's turn back to the SIP and just translate the `processedStringLiteral` production rule.

> A `processedStringLiteral` is an `alphaid` followed by a quote followed by one or more `printableChar`s (except for quote or the dollar sign) or `escape`s (with possible intermingling of the two) ending in another quote.
>
> Alternatively it is an `alphaid` followed by three quotes followed by one or more of the following: up to two consecutive quotes followed by any `char` except another quote or dollar sign or an `escape`. You can then add any number of quotes followed by a final three quotes.

* EBNF is not powerful enough to describe all grammars. It only describes grammars known as [context free grammars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).